# integration$\int \frac{e^x}{x}dx$

Tags: integration

I want to integrate $\int \frac{e^x}{x}dx$.

Attempt 1: Let $u = e^x$, and $dv = \frac{1}{x}dx$ i.e. $v = \log x$. Then by integration by parts, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\int \frac{e^x}{x}dx &= \int u\, dv \\
&= uv - \int v\, du \\
&= e^x\log x - \underbrace{\int e^x\log x\,dx}_{=?}
\end{align}
$$

Attempt 2: Let $u = \frac{1}{x}$ and $dv = e^xdx$. Then similarly we have
$$
\begin{align}
\int \frac{e^x}{x}dx &= uv - \int v\, du \\
&=\frac{e^x}{x} - \int e^x\Big(-\frac{1}{x^2}\Big)dx \\
&=\frac{e^x}{x} + \underbrace{\int\frac{e^x}{x^2}dx}_{=?}
\end{align}
$$

I tried choosing different $u$s by using integration by parts, but none worked

Does anyone have a better idea?

Comment: This is not an elementary integral. Check the exponential integral.

Comment: I don't think this is a very simple integral to evaluate, but what you have done is correct.

Comment: It would be nice if you would try to learn mathjax, see help page, and not to expect us to read your not too excellent handwriting.

Comment: sorry about my awkward handwriting ,as my native language is not English , it is not easy for me to surf through the whole website , I will try using what you called mathjax next time ,thank you

Comment: @user143997 [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a link that you can use to learn the fundamental of mathjax (/latex)

Comment: See [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Answer (score 2):

This is a textbook example of an integral that can't be expressed with traditional set of analytical functions. With a specific choice of the integrating constant, you get the exponential integral $\operatorname{Ei}(x)$.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral

Comment: thank you very much ,orion ,now I see what I am gonna do